# How to get date information in a microcontroller running on ETAS OS?

Tags: c, date, embedded, rtos

I need the current date information. I am thinking of using time.h standard library. But I am not sure if time.h could provide current date in ETAS OS. Does anyone know anything about this?

Comment: I want to know how time.h is used to get the date. I know it works in my PC, but is it taking the system time, will it work if I run it in another platform with ETAS OS?

Comment: First you need to figure out what the source of the time information would be which is available on your target hardware... an RTC?  Initialized from what?  A network time server?